# Изменить формат даты через регулярные выражения

Tags: python

Необходимо даты формата mm/dd/yyyy, замените их на dd/mm/yyyy. 
Нужно сохранять разделители между dd, mm и yyyy. Тоесть если задали на вход Сегодня 04/24/2022. На выходе должно быть Сегодня 24/04/2022. Если задали Сегодня 04.24.2022. На выходе должно быть Сегодня 24.04.2022.
Для разделителей используются символы . и /. Их трогать не нужно.
Мой код

```
import re
s=input()
res1 = re.sub(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})',r'\2/\1/\3',s)
print(res1)
```

Но, у меня работает только, если разделитель /, а если . то не работает. Как сделать, чтобы и / и точка появлялись в зависимости какой разделитель на входе

Comment: `res1 = re.sub(r'(\d{2})(\W)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})',r'\4\2\3\2\1',s)` так же захватывать в группу и возвращать на место

Comment: вот такой примерно должен быть заголовок

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s=input()
res1 = re.sub(r'(\d{2})(\W)(\d{2})\2(\d{4})',r'\3\2\1\2\4',s)
print(res1)
```

Comment: А зачем вы в качестве своего ответа оформили комментарий другого участника? Пометьте ответ как общий, в таком случае.

Comment: Я немного тот ответ исправил. У него сначала выводится год, потом месяц, потом день. А по условию задачи нужно было чуть-чуть не так. Сначала месяц, потом день, потом год. Поэтому решил подкорректировать комментарий другого участника, чтобы показать более точный ответ на вопрос задачи.

Comment: ну так принципиальное решение было предложено как раз другим участником, а не вами. в таких случаях было бы справедливо сделать ответ общим.